# Lookup: Nintex forms 2013 with External SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, nintex-workflow

Is it possible to have a Nintex forms lookup with external sharepoint list? I've many SQL tables and I need to use the data on the form. I'm creating an external list using BCS. I was able to show external list data in a dropdown using list lookup but having a lookup based on this dropdown selection isn't working!

Answer (score 0):

First you'd need to create an external Content Type in SharePoint using SharePoint Designer. Then on required site/list create new "External data" column.

In Nintex Forms use "External data column" control in order to display and manipulate the data.

Comment: Okay, but I was unable do lookup based on a selection. That's what my requirement is.

Comment: I'm not sure why are you using a lookup. If you are having another list with values from this external column you might need to write a JSOM code to achieve that.